# NoSuchMethodError when i try to play video in Vimeo

Tags: java, android, vimeo

I try to play vimeo video but showing me this error. what i need to do?

dependency like:- `dependencies {

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.5.0"
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':gpuv')
// ad templete
implementation project(':nativetemplates')
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.21'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.6'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.0.7'
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.29'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3'
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4.LTS'
implementation 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.41'
implementation 'org.mp4parser:muxer:1.9.41'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:3.0.3'
implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4'
// video compress
implementation 'com.zolad:videoslimmer:1.0.0'
  // pick media object
implementation 'per.freesky1102.mediapicker:mediapicker:1.0.0'
// image editor
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native'
// vimeo video extractor library
implementation 'com.ct7ct7ct7.androidvimeoplayer:library:1.2.2'
// scratch card
implementation 'com.github.cooltechworks:ScratchView:v1.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method priority(Lcom/bumptech/glide/Priority;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions' appears in /data/app/~~tQ1ThUqDynAA0a8fQT1l2A==/app.example.com-ai-A_YlHjpQVAFZAkbdKwO==/base.apk)

```
getLifecycle().addObserver(vimeoPlayer);
    //      vimeoPlayer.setFullscreenVisibility(true);
    vimeoPlayer.initialize(true, (int) videoid);
    vimeoPlayer.loadVideo((int) videoid);
    vimeoPlayer.seekTo(1.0f);
    vimeoPlayer.play();
    vimeoPlayer.clearCache();
```

Comment: can you share your dependency declarations? looks like a version mismatch

Comment: @yahorbarkouski implementation 'com.ct7ct7ct7.androidvimeoplayer:library:1.2.2

Comment: can you share the full gradle build file? at least dependencies part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done this thing after one day research, just degrade glide, like:-

implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

The `glide-transformations` library is known to have a transitive dependency on an older version of `Glide`, [the snippet](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/main/build.gradle) from the latest `jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.3.0`:

```kotlin
buildscript {
  ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    glide_version = '4.11.0' <-----
    gpuimage_version = '2.1.0'
  }
  ...
}
```

I can propose to consider 2 ways:

1. (Preferred) Update `jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations` to the latest, `4.3.0` version, so you'll get transitive `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0`
2. Use the desired `4.12.0` version of `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide` strictly, having the configuration like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.bumptech.glide' && details.requested.name == 'glide') {
            details.useVersion '4.14.2'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working with your recommended code.